# Pycharm - How to find usages in template

Tags: django, pycharm

It seems that find usages command doesn't show usages inside template files. Is there some settings for that?

Answer (score 3):

I right click on the root of the project and do "Find in Path..."

Comment: Exactly what I am doing now, seems like the only way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that went away after I told PyCharm where to find the settings.py file.

Try looking in Settings -> Project Settings -> Django Support.  The "Settings" box was empty so I directed it to the settings.py file and restarted and it worked after that.

There were 3 other form elements on that page, "Enable Django Support" (which was checked), "Django project root" (which was correct for my project), and "Manage script" (correctly set to manage.py).